# How to get rooms after adding redis

Tags: node.js, socket.io, pm2, socket.io-redis

Works without Redis. But I need to add it to work with multiple hosts, because... I use pm2 on my project. When I enable Redis adapter (commented strings in serversideConnect.ts) => get error:

```
Create socket host!
Socket connected, ID:  iyAnIThaSILp-4zuAAAB
Join room!!!
project_path/node_modules/socket.io/dist/socket.js:535
return this.adapter.socketRooms(this.id) || new Set();
TypeError: this.adapter.socketRooms is not a function
```

If I enable without **io.adapter(redis({host: 'localhost', port: 6379}));** I get when console.log('rooms: ', io.sockets.adapter.rooms) => Map { '_L6Jh6SrZaS1nU7ZAAAB' => Set { '_L6Jh6SrZaS1nU7ZAAAB' } }, with redis adapter => {}

// server.ts

```
import serversideConnectSocket from '../socket/serversideConnect';
const app: Express = express();
const server: http.Server = http.createServer(app);
serversideConnectSocket(server);
```

// serversideConnect.ts

```
const sockets = require('socket.io');
// const redis = require('socket.io-redis');

import chatServer from './socketForVChat';


const bindListeners = (io) => {
    io.on('connection', socket => chatServer(socket, io));
};

const initializeSocketHost = (server) => {
    console.log('Create socket host!');
    const io = sockets(server, {
        transports: ['websocket', 'polling']
    });
    // io.adapter(redis({host: 'localhost', port: 6379}));
    bindListeners(io);
}

export default initializeSocketHost;
```

// socketForVChat

```
export default (socket, io) => {
    console.log('Socket connected, ID: ', socket.id);
    socket.on(SOCKET_ACTIONS.JOIN_ROOM, data => {
        const { rooms: joinedRooms } = socket;

        if (Array.from(joinedRooms).includes(roomID)) {
            return console.warn('Already connected');
        }
        const clients = Array.from(io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(roomID) || []);
        console.log('socket clients: ', clients);
        console.log('room: ', roomID);
    }
}
```